# Can I ignore time ticks while I'm debugging? (stopped execution due to breakpoint hit)

Tags: ios, debugging, c++11, clang, sdl

I'm building a little game to improve my c++11 knowledge using SDL2 for iOS.

The gameloop is implemented using locked steps for the game logic (simulation), and variable steps for the rendering.

The problema I have is: whenever I set a breakpoint in my code to inspect something, and then resume the execution, the time I spent looking at the code is taken into account to compute the frame's time. 
So if I spend 5secs looking at the code, and hit 'continue' the next frame time +5secs. This means that in the gameloop, the logic simulation advances the game world as if 5seconds have passed, which is really annoying.

So my question: is there any way I can attach to some callback/signal to know when the execution stops/resumes  and be able to ignore the time passing while debugging?

I'm using XCode7, `clang --version` issues this output:

> Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0

Comment: There might be (and I would be interested to hear it too), but it is very likely to be simpler just fallback to default time step (e.g. 16ms) if passed interval is definitely too huge (say more than 1 second).

Comment: Yep, i've implemented that solution, but I'm still curious, as either way you miss a frame. If the simulation frame has a high frequency you still end up advancing the game simulation quite a bit